# Why is PCA often used before t-sne for problems when the goal is only to reduce dimensionality?

Tags: pca, tsne

Ex: Matlab's t-sne tutorials frequently use PCA

https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/tsne-settings.html

" Process Data Using t-SNE

Obtain two-dimensional analogs of the data clusters using t-SNE. Use the Barnes-Hut algorithm for better performance on this large data set. Use PCA to reduce the initial dimensions from 784 to 50. <- **(1) Why are we using PCA here to reduce dimensions to 50 first at all if we are going to use t-sne after PCA to reduce to 2 dimensions anyway?**

Matlab Tutorial Code: https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/tsne-settings.html

```matlab
rng default % for reproducibility 

Y = tsne(X,'Algorithm','barneshut','NumPCAComponents',50); 

figure gscatter(Y(:,1),Y(:,2),L)
```

1) See question bolded above

2) What would you have googled to find this out?

I had googled "Why is PCA often used before t-sne for problems when the goal is only to reduce dimensionality? "

Answer (score 3):

t-SNE is computationally expensive, more than PCA. Many examples might use PCA just to simplify the problem.

Moreover, it is explained [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210120195626/http://simranmetric.com/practical-considerations-for-using-tsne/):

> If the data set is high dimensional, doing principal component
> analysis is recommended because otherwise the curse of dimensionality
> can be an issue. TSNE makes the assumption of local linearity which
> might not hold in high dimensions where the manifold may be varying
> and PCA can help alleviate this issue by reducing the dimensionality
> of the data.

In other words, it seems that t-SNE suffers from high dimensionality of your data. It is typically used to represent a manifold in 2-3 dimensions, not tens or hundreds like, for example, PCA. It's mostly a visualization tool IMHO.

---

On the googling part, I suggest you to search only for the most relevant elements of your search, not for articulated sentences. I googled something like: `"why pca before tsne"` and it was enought to find useful stuff. Browsers don't need syntactic coherence, just the right keywords.